# Inserting a text between 2 patterns

Tags: sed, xml

I have a `.xml` file which contains the below

```
<controller-host></controller-host>
 <controller-port></controller-port>
<tier-name></tier-name>
<node-name></node-name>
```

I want the output like this

```
<controller-host>AppDynamicsHost</controller-host>
 <controller-port>80</controller-port>
<tier-name>**the host name**</tier-name>
<node-name>tomcat server</node-name>
```

I tried to use `sed` but not able to.

Comment: What Attempts with `sed` have you tried so far? We may be able to  help iron it out.

Answer (score 3):

The file that is given is not valid xml. You have to add opening and closing root tags. Like this:

```
<xml>
  <controller-host></controller-host>
  <controller-port></controller-port>
  <tier-name></tier-name>
  <node-name></node-name>
</xml>
```

---

With that input you can use an xml parser like `xmlstartlet` to edit the contents:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -u //controller-host -v "AppDynamicsHost" \
                 -u //controller-port -v "80" \
                 -u //tier-name -v "the hostname" \
                 -u //node-name -v "tomcat server" file
```

- `ed` start editing mode of `xmlstartlet`
- `-O` omit the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` declaration
- `-u` update the given xpath
- `-v` set the given value

---

The output would then be:

```
<xml>
  <controller-host>AppDynamicsHost</controller-host>
  <controller-port>80</controller-port>
  <tier-name>the hostname</tier-name>
  <node-name>tomcat server</node-name>
</xml>
```

To edit the file directly inplace you can use the `-L` flag.

Comment: But i do not have xmlstartlet in my amazon instances. Is there any other way 1. installing xmlstartlet and 2 . using Ruby

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$host='hostname'

sed -i 's/<controller-host><\/controller-host>/<controller-host>AppDynamicsHost<\/controller-host>/' yourfile.xml
sed -i 's/<controller-port><\/controller-port>/<controller-port>80<\/controller-port>' yourfile.xml
sed -i "s/<tier-name><\/tier-name>/<tier-name>${host}<\/tier-name>/' yourfile.xml
sed -i 's/<node-name><\/node-name>/<node-name>tomcat server<\/node-name>/' yourfile.xml
```

The `-i` flag means to write the result into your file, try running this without the `-i` while testing.

Comment: I have a xml file whic contains teh below 

<controller-host></controller-host>
 <controller-port></controller-port>
<tier-name></tier-name>
<node-name></node-name>
            
                                                                                                                                                     I want the output liek this 
<controller-host>AppDynamicsHost</controller-host>
 <controller-port>80</controller-port>
<tier-name>**the host name**</tier-name>
<node-name>tomcat server</node-name>

Comment: 1. sed -n  '/<controller/,/<\/controller-port/p' test.sh
2. sed -i '/controller/,/controller/' test.sh

Answer (score 1):

As chaos said, making the file a valid XML file and using `xmlstarlet` or similar xml processing tool (e.g. `xsh`) is the "right" answer...but if you just want to do simple templating then you would modify your input file to have easily found and replaceable tokens in the locations you want to be able to change.  For example:

```
<controller-host>__CONTROLLER__</controller-host>
 <controller-port>__PORT__</controller-port>
<tier-name>__HOSTNAME__</tier-name>
<node-name>__NODENAME__</node-name>
```

Then you can use any of the usual tools (awk, sed, perl, ruby, whatever) to replace `__CONTROLLER__` etc with the actual values you want them to have.

NOTE: it is very important to use strings that do not otherwise occur in the text - that's why i've used `__` as part of the replacable strings, e.g. `__PORT__` rather than just `PORT`.

This works for very simple templating needs - if you need to do more complicated templating, many languages have very sophisticated templating libraries - e.g. `perl` has `Text::Template` (and many others - it's a common problem that has inspired many solutions)

Comment: anonymous downvoter: what do you find so objectionable about this answer?  templating like this has been done for decades, long before things like XML existed.

Comment: All answers in this question were anonymously downvoted. It seems someone here doesn't like XML =) But however you have my upvote.